# Can i ban technical scope extension as a tech lead

Tags: team, teamwork, team-building, collaboration

I am tech lead of a team with decided architecture and an action plan for development divided in different phases. One of the developers, a very vocal one, wants to pick a task from one of the later scopes. Am I in my right as a tech lead to ban his wish and what if the other members of the team are indifferent to it?

Comment: There is no official definition of what a tech-lead's role is, it will depend on your company. In some places you will have authority to decide that stuff. In others you will be expected to persuade your team to do the right thing, rather than order them to.

Comment: @mattfreake honestly this tech lead role is a crap :)

Comment: In others you will be expected to lead by consensus when possible and refer to management if that can't be achieved. In others ... Ask your manager for tips on how to handle this.

Comment: You or their manager set the priorities not them, if you don’t want to do that, don’t complain if the engineer chooses their own tasks

Comment: Why does he want to pick up that task? Boredom or lack of ability with the current/next ones? He doesn't agree with the priorities? Resume driven development? To solve this you first have to get to the motivation. As a tech lead you likely have the authority.

Answer (score 6):

No. But you can de-prioritize it, preferably with everyone's agreement. "Great idea, but it isn't the most important thing to work on right now. Put it in the tracking system as technical debt so we don't forget it, maybe give it a best-guess sizing estimate so we know what it'd cost us to do properly. and we'll get to it when we can spare the resources."

I've been in both sides of that discussion many times. If they can convince you that it's cheap enough and important enough, or that it will make future work sufficiently easier, you can prioritize it higher. Meanwhile, there's all this other stuff that needs to be done sooner...

Answer (score 2):

This might need a perspective change.

To think that you would want to "ban" someone from doing something that's not yet in scope is a bit awkward.  It means that you wish to suppress their creativity at some level.

As a tech lead, you want to avoid this at all costs.  Nothing kills your team's morale quite like sending the signal to your teammates that they cannot innovate or take something else on.

How you phrase this is to say "yes, and".  Some sample ways to go about it:

- Yes, we can do this, and we should get buy-in to be sure that doing this early won't cause us to slip our deliverable.
- Yes, and we should look to include our stakeholder(s) in on this so that they're aware of the plan.

Being flexible and open to change in this way will garner more trust within your group since you appear to be willing to adjust, and it'll also encourage more alignment with the plan, since the group would need to accept that there may not be buy-in or alignment with the approach.

Answer (score 1):

For this specific case: in the same way that a parent can decide anything and say "because I said so", it's probably within your power. But if you want to keep the respect of your team, I would have a discussion with this developer about why they want to do this, weigh the pros and cons with them, and come to a resolution where they feel like they were heard.

In terms of making a blanket policy going forwards, I would have a similar approach - don't make an absolute decree, and go with something more along the lines of "We need to more or less follow the action plan, so please try to only do tasks within the scope of our current phase. If you find something that you *really* think should be done in this phase, then bring it to my attention and we can discuss it first before you start on it".

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to move this to a 1:1 and talk through it.

The obvious issues are dependencies and side-effect. If you do things further down the pipeline, then its dependencies may not be in place, and the side-effects may not be detected because the component is not expected to be online yet. It'll take time to evaluate this. Let the developer know the extra overhead of doing what he's doing and ask him how he plans on ensuring that this out-of-sequence feature will not cause major development issues such as locking into an architecture that has yet to be put in place.

This exercise is great to see if he has suitable team-lead qualities, and I wouldn't dismiss it with a straight up "ban". If he's able to think big picture and come up with solutions and alternatives, then that's something you want him to do despite doing things "out of order".

In the grand scheme of things, if the feature has no negative side-effects, then there's no reason to deny him that, **IF** he's the one that provides all the proof and guarantees. He needs to know that if anything goes wrong regarding his implementation of features out of order, it's on him.